# Cannot upgrade aurelia-cli from 0.21.0 to 0.23.0

Tags: aurelia

When I try to upgrade aurelia-cli from 0.21.0 to 0.23.0 on Mac OS X 10.11.6, `au -v` displays the version as 0.21.0 instead of 0.23.0. I even tried the following, to no avail.

```
npm uninstall aurelia-cli -g
npm cache clean
npm install aurelia-cli -g
au -v
0.21.0

npm outdated

Package               Current            Wanted            Latest
aurelia-cli            0.21.0            0.23.0            0.23.0
```

Comment: Are you running this command inside an Aurelia project?

Comment: @AshleyGrant Yes.

Comment: @AshleyGrant The package.json has this: "aurelia-cli": "^0.23.0" and if I run au -v in a non-aurelia project directory, I get 0.23.0.

Comment: gotcha. I'll post an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few things you'll need to do. First, and based on your comments, you may have already done this: you need to run `npm install aurelia-cli --save-dev`. This will update the *local* version of the Aurelia CLI. Each Aurelia project gets its own local version of the CLI so that upgrading your global version of the CLI won't magically break something in a project. This is especially important currently with the CLI in alpha and thus the possibility of breaking changes being somewhat likely.

If you have already done this and you're still seeing `0.21.0` when you run `au -v`, then run `rm -rf node_modules` in the project directory and then `npm install`. Sometimes npm can be a pain in the butt.

As you are moving from `v0.21.0` of the CLI to `v0.23.0`, you will need to follow the instructions for updating your `aurelia.json` file found [here](https://github.com/aurelia/cli/releases/tag/0.23.0). These instructions are unrelated to the problem you're having, but you need to be aware of them.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Forgot the CLI version is per-project! Thanks!

Comment: You may want to enhance the [upgrade instructions](https://github.com/aurelia/cli/releases/tag/0.23.0) to include running `npm install requirejs requirejs/text —save`.

Comment: Would you mind submitting a PR for that? You can edit changelog.md